# Issue with voice performance between two ip phones at the same site connecting to two different CUCM?

Tags: cisco, ipsec, voip, sip

I have one branch which is (branch-1) with two groups of ip phones, one group is connecting to CUCM-1 in HQ and the other group is connecting to CUCM-2 in the branch (branch-1) and the connectivity between HQ and branch-1 is through IPsec and the link between CUCMs is SIP trunk with default configuration and they are working fine,

Then I have branch-2 which also have two groups of ip phones connecting to CUCM-1 in HQ and CUCM-2 in Branch-1 but when i call from a phone connecting to CUCM-1 to CUCM-2 it can ring and when I answer i can't hear any thing.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

HQ connecting to branch-1 through IPsec

HQ connecting to branch-2 through IPsec

Branch-1 is connecting to branch-2 through IPsec.

---

CUCM-1 located in HQ

CUCM-2 Located in Branch-1

SIP trunk configured in between
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Who can advise what's the problem ??

Comment: My guess would be a routing problem or the IPsec configuration, but without device configurations or a diagram, it's impossible to say.  Can you provide those?